# How can I pass arguments to Java with AndroidJavaObject.Call?

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, unity-game-engine

So i've integrated my project with eclipse and make calls to my Java classes through C# calls:

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
jo.Call("Trigger");
```

Now providing I dont try to pass any arguments along with the Trigger method call, it calls the method perfectly. However, if i try to pass the variable through as follows:

```
jo.Call("Trigger", "my string");
```

The unity engine thinks the mystring arg is referring to the signature type of the method being called. How can i pass variables through along to my Java method?

On top of this, how do i return variables from java to C#? Would it be as simple as

```
String myString = jo.Call("Trigger");
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it like this. It is working for me:

```
using(AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
{
     using(AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
     {
          jo.Call("Trigger", "my string");
     }
}
```

And then in Eclipse you do:

```
void Trigger(String message)
{
     if(message=="my string")...
}
```

Sending variable from java to C#:
In eclipse you do:

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Android", "ReceiveVar", "some string");
```

Where `"Android"` is Script containing `"ReceiveVar(string str)"` function, and `"some string"` is your variable (this is Unity part).